# Unable to store a json object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to store a JSON object in my database using mongoose. I've made my schema and modeled it.

I've tried setting the type to object, but that didn't help. The data I'm trying to put in is present here: https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=test

My code is:

```js
    body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);
        const log = new model.Log({
            useragent: data.useragent,
            browserName: data.browser.name,
            browserVersion: data.browser.version,
            browserMajorVersion: parseInt(data.browser.majorVersion, 10),
            deviceType: type,
            CPu: data.CPU,
            OSName: data.OS.name,
            OSVersion: data.OS.version,
            mobileOS: mobileOS,
            ipAddress: ipAddress,
            ipData: body (I've tried doing ipData: { ip: body.ip, ...} too)
        });
```

My schema:

```js
const connectLogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    useragent: String,
    browserName: String,
    browserVersion: String,
    browserMajorVersion: Number,
    deviceType: String,
    CPU: String,
    OSName: String,
    OSVersion: String,
    mobileOS: String,
    ipAddress: String,
    idData: {
            ip: String,
            is_eu: Boolean,
            city: String,
            region: String,
            region_code: String,
            country_name: String,
            country_code: String,
            continent_name: String,
            continent_code: String,
            latitude: Number,
            longitude: Number,
            postal: String,
            calling_code: String,
            flag: String,
            emoji_flag: String,
            emoji_unicode: String,
        asn: {
            asn: String,
            name: String,
            domain: String,
            route: String,
            type: String
        },
        languages: [new mongoose.Schema({name: String, native: String})],
        currency: {
            name: String,
            code: String,
            symbol: String,
            native: String,
            plural: String
        },
        time_zone: {
            name: String,
            abbr: String,
            offset: String,
            is_dst: Boolean,
            current_time: String
        },
        threat: {
            is_tor: Boolean,
            is_proxy: Boolean,
            is_anonymous: Boolean,
            is_known_attacker: Boolean,
            is_known_abuser: Boolean,
            is_threat: Boolean,
            is_bogon: Boolean
        }
    },
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: () => moment().utc().format() }
});
```

An empty ipData field shows up in the database, with only the languages array but it too being empty. At this point I'm lost and I have no idea what to do next, please help!

Comment: Just to make things clear, is the req.body object holding all your data that you want to save in the database?

Comment: @SamiShamesEl-Deen Yes, its the body object of the callback of the request module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misspelled ipData, idData. If anyone stumbles upon this later by mistake, please check the spellings.